# datatables.net plugin hides left menu behind table in IE

Tags: html, css, datatables

I had a page that works perfectly in IE.
Then I added the wonderful jQuery plugin [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) to it using this code in DOMReady with this code

```
$('#articlestable-container table').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

Everything is fine in Webkit and Firefox browsers. See the image.

[image: Rendering in Firefox]

But in IE, the table hides the menu that ideally should come over the table like this.

[image: Rendering in IE]

As you can see, the sub-menu gets rendered behind the table.

I don't think z-index is the culprit here. The sub-menu has `z-index: 9999;` anyway.
What could be wrong? Any pointers to solve this will be very helpful.

Comment: What about the position of sub-menu.

Comment: Dear its a z-index issue. i dont have your working code/fiddle other wise would have solved it for you.

Comment: @Dinesh Swami: Then why is it displayed correctly in FIrefox / Webkit?

Comment: @Exor: Thanks. positioning was the problem. the wrapper was positioned  relative and so this error happened! do you know why that would happen in IE? thanks a lot once more

Answer (score 1):

Have been using the default CSS that ships with datatables.net. Here the wrapper was having `position:relative;`. Just remove that code and the menu appears properly.

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
    /*position: relative;*/
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1;  /*Feeling sorry for IE */
}
```

I guess that its an IE bug. http://www.gobdg.com/blog/2009/04/positionrelative-z-index-ie-bug/
But manually setting `z-index:1;` didn't work for me.

Disclaimer: I don't know yet as to how this actually solved the issue. I am no CSS guru.

Comment: I told you dear i dont have your working code other wise i would solved your issues. IE7 always give problem specially z-index and positioning. Any ways glad you solved your issue.

Comment: great answer. i was also having same issue. my time saved :)